# SO HTML formats time incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See this SO question: [Parsing non-standard date string from Stack Overflow into a .NET DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282069/parsing-non-standard-date-string-from-stackoverflow-into-a-net-datetime).

It seems to me that if you are going to use the Universal Sortable time format, you should omit the timezone qualifier as it is already implicit in the time specification.  The Z on the end of the time implies Zulu or UTC.

Comment: I'm the author of that question, and I'd just like to say that my issue did not arise from the data dump, but from the actual HTML generated on the site (http://stackoverflow.com). I'm not sure whether the data dump has the same issue or not.

Comment: Including timezone information twice is a bug.  A very minor one, but a bug nonetheless.  I don't personally care about what format is used -- it's only in the title and I'm not scraping the page -- but it ought to be a valid date/time format if it's going to be there at all.

Comment: Now my scraper's broken ;) Glad this is fixed - mouseover the time next to my name after the comment.

Comment: and my greasemonkey script is broken. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oh, I see, you want to drop UTC in favor of the Z. Ok, we can do that..