# What's the "Z" in the Joined date tooltip mean?

Tags: support, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool-tip timestamp shows a Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15986/tool-tip-timestamp-shows-a-z)

[image: Tooltip shows 2009-06-27 00:00:00Z]

It's present in the "Question Asker" one, as well:

[image]

And the "answerer" one:

[image]

Is this some form of usage I'm unfamiliar with, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Z = Zulu](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/military/z.html).

As in all time is based on UTC or GMT.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why all these times can't be displayed in the user's local time zone... It'd certainly be far more useful/usable.

Comment: But then it'd be harder for people to figure out when cap rollover was!  And there would be endless whining!

Comment: Except that you could default it go GMT and on your preferences where you'd change it, changing your timezone would then change a display saying when the rollover was, etc. That's an easy problem to solve.