# What is the Z in the time displayed on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool-tip timestamp shows a Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15986/tool-tip-timestamp-shows-a-z)

In recent activity tab, the times are displayed as

```
2010-03-07 00:00:00Z to 2010-03-14 23:59:59Z
```

What is **Z**?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15986/tool-tip-timestamp-shows-a-z

Answer (score 5):

Universal Coordinated Time (which replaced Greenwich Mean Time) is also known as [Zulu](http://www.aos.wisc.edu/~hopkins/aos100/z-time.htm) time.